# Prove that the set with $c^a$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $A = \{$prime integers$\}$
>    $B = \{$odd, positive multiples of $5$$\}$
>    $C = \{(b^a)/(a^b)|a \in A, b \in B\}$
>
> **Prove that $C\cup \{c^a|a \in A, c \in C\}$ is countable.**

I have no idea how to go about this. Can I say that since a subset of a countable set is countable, $C$ is therefore countable: it maps onto $\mathbb{N}$ and so I am essentially just proving $\mathbb{N}^a$? This is correct? How would I prove even that part?

Comment: It looks like your set is a subset of the rational numbers.

Comment: @Braindead I am suffering from a condition similar to your username, and cannot figure out how to apply your comment to the proof. Is it enough to just say that if it's a subset of a countable set, it's therefore also countable? Do I actually need to care about what's inside set A and B in this question?

Comment: It is true that a subset of a countable set is countable. Is this a homework problem for a class, or are you just doing this problem for your own personal understanding?

Comment: A more challenging problem would be to have $a^c$ rather than $c^a$.

Comment: @Braindead It is a homework question, but it would also be very helpful for personal understanding. Why is $a^c$ more challenging than $c^a$?

Comment: An element of $C$ is going to be a fraction. If you take $a$ and raise it to a fractional power $c$, it is no longer necessarily a rational number.